# Q: How to use an inline prototype in a sandbox gateway?

Tags: inline, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway

We are using WSO2 API manager, version 2.1.0, for publishing our APIs.

On the other hand, we want to use the inline prototyping feature to mock the APIs not developed yet.

In our installation, we have separate gateways (production and sandbox), as described in
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Publish+through+Multiple+API+Gateways

Our problem is that all inline prototyped APIs are deployed in production endpoint (and this endpoint is protected). Is there any way to use inline, but with sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

This is already identified[1] and fixed through WUM update. If you have a valid subscription you can use wum tool[2] to update your api manager 2.1.0 distribution

[1] - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5954
[2] - https://wso2.com/updates/wum

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Roshan
I think that maybe we are talking about 2 different things. I'm asking about **inline** prototyping (embebed javascript), not deployed prototyping. Is this update solving the same issue?
In any case, thanks!